# What are the advantages of C# object/list initializer syntax?

Tags: c#, initializer-list, initializer

1. Are there any speed gains when initializing a large amount of static objects?
2. Are there any compile-time or other kinds of advantages?

e.g:

```
IList<object> objects = new List<object>
{
    new object(),
    new object(),
    new object()
};
```

vs:

```
IList<object> objects = new List<object>();
objects.Add(new object());
objects.Add(new object());
objects.Add(new object());
```

Comment: 1 - it's a more readable, less boilerplate-bloated syntax. 2 - `new object()` does not make any sense. 3 - use `var` instead of typing the same thing twice `IList<object> objects = new List<object>();` in the same line of code. C# is not java. 4 - No it does not provide any runtime benefit. It compiles to the same IL.

Comment: Doesn't using var for every object in your code add a large compile-time overhead? :)
I learned to use it sparingly for objects with large names such as IDictionary<TKey, TVal> .... etc.

Comment: no it doesn't.inferring a type is a trivial job for compiler. @HighCore I think you should write it as answer instead of comment

Comment: Ok, well awesome, learning lots of things every day :)
Also, yeah @HighCore, please write the solution as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no run time difference between these two pieces of code.  They will both compile down to the same IL.

The primary advantage of the initializer syntax would be that it basically initializes a list in a single expression as opposed to across multiple statements.  For example, you could use it to return a list from a method without explicitly creating a temporary variable (the compiler creates this temporary for you):

```
public List<T> MakeListOf3<T>( T val )
{
    return new List<T> { val, val, val };
}
```

As opposed to:

```
public List<T> MakeListOf3<T>( T val )
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    list.Add( val );
    list.Add( val );
    list.Add( val );
    return list;
}
```

That's quite contrived, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically a syntactical sugar and it's rather a matter of personal taste and aesthetics.

Also, it's worth mentioning that it's possible to combine collection initializers and object initializers. You can than build in one run pretty complex structures, e.g.:

```
Product product = new Product
{
    Name = "Dog food",
    Price = 9.95,
    Manufacturer =
    {
        Name = "Dog food producer"
        Location = "Some location"
    },
    SimilarProducts =
    {
        new Product { Name = "Cat food" },
        new Product { Name = "Bird food", Price = 5.50},
        new Product 
        { 
            Name = "Guinea Pig food", 
            Price = 5.50
            SimilarProducts = 
            { 
                new Product { Name = "Guinea Pig shampoo" }, 
                new Product { Name = "Guinea Pig toofpaste" }
            },
        },
    },
}
```